# Chemical Equilibrium - Why does changing the temperature shift the equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, physical-chemistry, equilibrium

I know that raising the temperature in a reversible chemical reaction causes the equilibrium to shift to the endothermic side.

I know that $\Delta G = \Delta H - T \Delta S$ but I don't know how to put them together to show why the equilibrium would shift.